# Is there a bug in the `arrows.meta` or `bending` library with the `double` option in TikZ 3.1.5b?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

When the `bending` library is loaded, the `double` arrows are no longer attached to the line.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

% Old arrows library prior to Tikz 3.0
\begin{scope}[>=latex]
\draw (90:1.5)--(0,0)--(0:1.5);
\draw [blue,,->] (0:5mm)arc[start angle=0,delta angle=90,radius=5mm];
\draw [red,double,->] (0:10mm)arc[start angle=0,delta angle=90,radius=10mm];
\node[align=left,anchor=west] at (0,-1){With old library\\ arrows  no bug};
\end{scope}

% New arrows.meta library introduced with Tikz 3.0
\begin{scope}[>={Triangle[]},xshift=4cm]
\draw (90:1.5)--(0,0)--(0:1.5);
\draw [blue,,->] (0:5mm)arc[start angle=0,delta angle=90,radius=5mm];
\draw [red,double,->] (0:10mm)arc[start angle=0,delta angle=90,radius=10mm];
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[>=Stealth,xshift=6cm]
\draw (90:1.5)--(0,0)--(0:1.5);
\draw [blue,,->] (0:5mm)arc[start angle=0,delta angle=90,radius=5mm];
\draw [red,double,->] (0:10mm)arc[start angle=0,delta angle=90,radius=10mm];
\node[align=left,anchor=center] at (0,-1){With new library\\ arrows.meta: bug};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've reported it here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/896.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: related : [Remove unwanted gap before the arrow ending a bezier curve in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624557/138900)