# Remove unwanted gap before the arrow ending a bezier curve in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrow-curve, bezier

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,draw] (N) at (15em,2ex) {};
  \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
  \draw[-latex] (C) .. controls (-2.6em,-1.5em) and ($(N.south west)-(1ex,1ex)$) .. (N.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields

[image: output]

As you see, there is an unwanted gap between the curve and the arrow tip. How can I remove it?

The same problem occurs if we change a circle node into an ellipse node (using `shapes`) with different axes.

Bug report: http://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1079 .

Comment: This is not a bug, but a deliberate implementation choice. The reason you see it is because of your extreme control point making the unshortened bezier curve a lot within the arrow. From the manual abut `flex` : "...some compromises are made in the implementation where accuracy was traded for speed, so the distance by which the line end is shifted is not necessarily exactly..."

Comment: Your control point is very close to the end point. -so the bezier starts almost horizontal and only at the very end it turn up and hit the end point in 45 deg.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thx and let's not play the bug-vs-feature game. To me, inaccurracy is a mishap recognized only at a large magnification. In my book, an arrow with a gap makes the reader raise his/her eyebrows and scratch his/her head because he/she doesn't know the semantics of the gap. Also note that the issue turns areas that are supposed to have a closed border to areas without a closed border — topologically inacceptable. Note that dropping the `bending` library makes the issue go away, so the default, issue-free code is apparently considered fast enough.

Comment: I am not playing any game with you. I am telling you how it is written in the manual. NOT a bug.

Comment: @hpekristiansen By merely stating this, you've started a useless ball game. Please stop this. It IS a bug because the specification of `bending`, `controls`, and arrow tips doesn't mention that something else is drawn than what was intended. It's only in the eye of some readers that what is drawn might hypothetically have some similarity to an arrow. Topologically, something completely different than specified is drawn. Nobody cares about which function is used under the hood at code line, say, 1107, and how that function is specified, and how inaccurate (=wrong) that function is implemented.

Comment: find someone else to play your ball game with

Comment: @hpekristiansen Since you're emotional and have an agenda, I refuse to argue with you.

Comment: related : [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553050/138900](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553050/138900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of `($(N.south west)-(1ex,1ex)$)` to `($(N.south west)-(3ex,1ex)$)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,draw] (N) at (15em,2ex) {};
  \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
  \draw[-latex] (C) .. controls (-2.6em,-1.5em) and ($(N.south west)-(3ex,1ex)$) .. (N.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit for illustration:

Sufficient distance: (2,1)

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

     \node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {1};
     \node[circle,draw] (b) at (1,1) {2};
     \node[circle,draw] (c) at (2,1) {3};
     \node[circle,draw] (d) at (2,0) {4};

    \draw[-latex] (a) .. controls (b) and (c) .. (d.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Insufficient distance: (2,0.1)

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

     \node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {1};
     \node[circle,draw] (b) at (1,1) {2};
     \node[circle,draw] (c) at (2,0.1) {3};
     \node[circle,draw] (d) at (2,0) {4};

    \draw[-latex] (a) .. controls (b) and (c) .. (d.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! After testing, even (1.5em,1ex) suffices. Any idea why the gap occurs?

Comment: @GeekestGeek I do not quite understand the math behind the control syntax but since the problem occurs once you lay a control point too close to the endpoint I guess the path gets something like undefined.

Comment: In you case, both control points are sufficiently far away: (2,0.1) is almost in the center of the circle 4 rather than on the border, isn't it?

Comment: @GeekestGeek No, there was a mistake in my graphic. The node No. 3 which was shown was not the one the arrow was "controlled" by. See the edit, now it is correct.

Comment: Thanks! The distance between (c.center) and (d.north west) seems to be 7.26pt (though, it looks more on the image).