# Using >=Stealth with double line seems to fail when the bending module is loaded

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I like the `Stealth[round,bend]` arrow tips, and recently discovered that they do not work as I expect when the line curved and doubled.  Playing with a small example, I found out that the `bend` parameter is not the problem, the problem is simply caused by loading the `bending` library.

Here is a small example that does not load the `bending` library:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[round]}]
  \node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node[draw] (B) at (2,0) {B};
  \draw[->]        (A) to[bend right] (B);
  \draw[->,double] (A) to[bend left] (B);
  \draw[->,double] (A) to (B);
  \draw[->,double] (A) to[loop above] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nice looking result]

Now if I uncomment the `\usetickzlibrary{bending}`, then the figure now gets rendered as follows.

[image: bad looking result]

Does anyone know a workaround to fix that?  Ideally I would like to use `>={Stealth[round,bend]}` so loading `\usetickzlibrary{bending}` seems necessary.

Comment: This post is almost identical to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553050/is-there-a-bug-in-the-arrows-meta-or-bending-library-with-the-double-optio). Such a behavior is a bug, that has already been [reported](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/896). Currently, you can fix it with this [workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624557/remove-unwanted-gap-before-the-arrow-ending-a-bezier-curve-in-tikz).

Comment: The TikZ library `bending` not only loads the `bending` module (which doesn't do much at all unless you use one of its option) but it sets `arrows=[flex]` which activates part of its working. You could do `\tikzset{double/.append style={arrows={[quick]}}}` to disable this again but then you need to define two different `Stealth` tips, one with `bend` (for non-doubled lines) and one without `bend` (or `flex`) for doubled and curved lines. But then you could just define `StealthDouble/.tip={Stealth[round,quick]}`.

Comment: Do you want a workaround that does support `bend` with curved doubled lines (then the bug needs to be fixed) or do you want to use the `bend`ing at least with non-doubled or non-curved lines?

Comment: I'm using bended arrows everywhere while drawing automata, but I'm only using doubled lines in a couple of places.  So disabling bending locally for double lines would be ok-ish as a workaround.  I'll try your `quick` trick, this sounds promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Qrrbrbirlbel's tip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659097/using-stealth-with-double-line-seems-to-fail-when-the-bending-module-is-loaded?noredirect=1#comment1640161_659097) about using `quick` to disable the flex computation that is broken for double line, I'm now using the following workaround to have bent arrows everywhere except when I need a double line.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[round,bend,length=4.75pt]},
                    % disable flex on double lines due to
                    % https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/896
                    StealthDouble/.tip={Stealth[round,quick,length=4.75pt]},
                    double>/.style={-StealthDouble,double}]
  \node[draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node[draw] (B) at (2,0) {B};
  \draw[->]      (A) to[bend right] (B);
  \draw[double>] (A) to[bend left] (B);
  \draw[double>] (A) to (B);
  \draw[double>] (A) to[loop above] (A);
  \draw[->] (B) to[loop above] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: workaround]